In AzureDevOps, link a Test Case/Point with a completed test run
In Azure Dev Ops, is there way to link a created Test Case/Test Point with a completed Test Run?
I have a pipeline that has run and completed tests but there is no link between those completed tests and the specific test point in the test plan.
Im currently running a pipeline that utilizes python/pytest and then uploads the results as an XML.

Hi Andrew Littell, have you tried plug pytest-ads-testplan? Did it work for you?

Currently, pytest isn't supported to associate automated tests with test cases. See the detailed info from this doc.

The following capabilities and limitations exist for each test type:

Coded UI test, Selenium tests, and unit tests written using Version 1 of the MSTest framework can be associated with a test case.
Tests that use MSTest v2, NUnit, and xUnit frameworks can be associated with a test case work item when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. However, these tests can't be run using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
Tests that use the .NET core framework can be associated with a test case work item when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. Run the .NET core tests. The appropriate target framework must be specified in a .runsettings file. However, these tests can't be run using Microsoft Test Manager and XAML builds.
Tests that use other test frameworks such as Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests such as Mocha or QUnit), or Jest cannot be associated with a test case.
Associating generic tests may work, but running these tests isn't supported.


You may try to use this plug pytest-ads-testplan to see your test results connected to your Test Plan. This pytest plugin will create an Azure Test Run and append TestResults to the test run as the tests are executed on a pipeline execution of a pytest test run.
